# Como remover uma página da navegação Ionic 2 / 3

Tags: ionic2, typescript, ionic3

Em uma aplicação híbrida com Ionic 3 possuo 3 páginas que fazem parte do processo de compra de um produto.

O processo é o seguinte:

1. O usuário está no carrinho e clica no botão "Escolher forma de pagamento"
2. Caso ele esteja *logado* é redirecionado para pagina de checkout
3. Se não estiver *logado* é redirecionado para página de autenticação
4. Se foi para autenticação e efetuou login eu redireciono para o checkout

Podemos imaginar um diagrama assim:

1. Se estiver *logado*

   [CARRINHO] => [CHECKOUT]
2. Se não estiver *logado*

   [CARRINHO] => [AUTENTICAÇÃO] => [CHECKOUT]

O problema é que se eu estou no checkout depois de ter autenticado e voltar para página anterior ele volta para página de autenticação e eu gostaria que ele pulasse ela e voltasse para o carrinho

Tentei inúmeras variações do código abaixo sem sucesso:

```
// Após autenticar com sucesso
this.navCtrl.push("CheckoutPage").then(() => {
    const index = self.navCtrl.getActive().index;
    self.navCtrl.remove(index);
});
```

Como eu posso remover uma página da navegação no Ionic 2/3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente subtrair -1 do índice do `navController`

ex:

```
this.navCtrl.push('CheckoutPage').then(() => {
   const index = self.navCtrl.getActive().index - 1;
   self.navCtrl.remove(index, 1);
});
```

Quando vc faz o push no `CheckoutPage` o mesmo é adicionado no índice, então removendo 1 (`self.navCtrl.getActive().index - 1`) você remove a view de autenticação e não a view `CheckoutPage`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado.